# How to play and record 2 channels with pyaudio using callback functions in python?

Tags: python, callback, pyaudio, recording

Has anyone had any luck playing audio and recording two channels simultaneously with pyaudio using callback functions? I have been messing around with this all day and I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far.

Thanks,

Zack

`def playandrec(self, insound, playch, rec_samp_len, recch):

```
# check to see if pg is active and stop it


if self.__pg != 0:
    if self.pgOpen == 1:
        self.delPage(self.pg)



# zero pad unused chanels    
self.__wf = np.zeros((insound.shape[0] + self.miscSampDelays, max(playch)), dtype=np.float32)

# fill in sound
if insound.ndim == 1:
    for i in range(insound.size):
        self.__wf[i][playch[0] - 1] = insound[i]
elif insound.ndim == 2:
    for j in range(insound.shape[1]):
        for i in range(insound.shape[0]):
            self.__wf[i][playch[j] - 1] = insound[i][j]
else:
    print('error goes here too may dims ')

# make a stream
pg = self.p.open(
    rate=self.fs,
    channels=max(recch),
    format=self.s.paFloat32,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    input_device_index=self.outdev,
    output_device_index=self.indev,
    frames_per_buffer=self.chunksize,
    stream_callback=self.__playandreccallback
)

# set var to pass
self.__pgOpen = 1
self.__playandrecCalled = 1
self.recch = recch
self.reccount = rec_samp_len
self.n = 0
self.__pg = pg
nmax = math.ceil(((rec_samp_len + self.miscSampDelays) / self.chunksize))
self.recsignal = np.zeros((self.chunksize * nmax, max(recch)), dtype=np.float32)

# start stream
pg.start_stream()

return pg`
```

```
def __playandreccallback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    """

    :param in_data:
    :param frame_count:
    :param time_info:
    :param status:
    :return:
    """

    chunk = self.__wf[(frame_count * self.n):((self.n + 1) * frame_count)]
    data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    # breakpoint()
    for idx in range(max(self.recch)):
        self.recsignal[self.n * frame_count:(self.n+1) * frame_count, idx] = data[idx::max(self.recch)]
    # ch1 = data[0::2]
    # ch2 = data[1::2]
    # breakpoint()



    self.n = self.n + 1

    if self.n * frame_count > self.reccount + self.miscSampDelays:
        # compleat
        tobeornottobe = pyaudio.paComplete
    else:
        tobeornottobe = pyaudio.paContinue

    return in_data, tobeornottobe
```

If i pass  in_data to the output the grows exponentially. If I pass anything but in_data the callback is only called once.